# how to close previous page if revisited

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following two html files.  submit.html opens newPage.html on submit and newPage.html opens submit.html on submit.  The problem is submit.html is playing an audio file in a hidden iframe.  How do I close submit.html so the music doesn't play over itself if the page is revisted?

submit.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Submit</title>
</head> 
<body>

   <iframe src="http://localhost/Audio/src/audio.html" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>  


   <form target="newPage" action=NewPage.html>
      <input type="submit" value="click">
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

newPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>newPage</title>
</head>
<body>
   here we are

   <form action="submit.html">
      <input type="submit" value="click">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using cookies somehow... to store in cookie value if page already visited so avoid playing audio again, all by js

Comment: remove iframe with audio.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to close the first sumbit.html page on button click, like this: `<input type="button" value="click" action="NewPage.html" onclick="self.close()">`

That way only one instance of the page will be opened when you submit on newpage.html.

The other better option would be to make a script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function windowClose() { 
window.open("http://www.yourdomain.com/submit.html"); 
window.close();
} 
</script>
```

Html

`<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="windowClose();">`

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  That closes submit from the submit page.  I need to be able to close submit.html from the newpage.html

Comment: This will close the submit page after you open the newpage.

Comment: I only want to close the old submit.html if I revisit it